# Latex style that resembles the one used in some computer science books

Tags: book-design

I would like to find a latex style that is close to the one used in books like the followings:

- Melvin Fitting, "First-Order Logic and Automated Theorem Proving" http://books.google.es/books?id=nYN0dBrCpmMC&pg=PA9
- Li and Vitányi, "An Introduction to Kolmogorov Complexity and Its Applications" http://books.google.es/books?id=25fue3UYDN0C&pg=PA259
- The CC-licensed book "Mathematics for Computer Science" available at http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring12/mcs.pdf

Does anybody know a similar layout format?

Answer (score 4):

At least the last book in your list is written with LaTeX:

```
boris@bilbo:~$ pdfinfo mcs.pdf 
Title:          
Subject:        
Keywords:       
Author:         
Creator:        LaTeX with hyperref package
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.10; modified using iText 2.1.7 by 1T3XT
CreationDate:   Mon Jun  4 15:49:40 2012
ModDate:        Mon Jun  4 15:49:53 2012
Tagged:         no
Pages:          828
Encrypted:      yes (print:yes copy:yes change:yes addNotes:yes)
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
File size:      9388308 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

I suggest you write to the authors and ask, which packages they used :)

Answer (score 4):

The copyright page for the Fitting book says it was “prepared from the author’s LaTeX files using Springer’s `svwidecm` style file.” Springer’s site does not have that style file, though they offer others intended for their authors’ drafts [here](http://www.springer.com/authors/book+authors?SGWID=0-154102-12-970131-0).

As Boris points out, the PDF metadata for the Lehman *et al.* book just says it was created by “LaTeX with hyperref package”, but it being CC-licensed you should be able to contact the authors and get the information from them.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the last book, the authors used the `times` package, but their summation signs are taken from the default Computer Modern set.